# The multi-part identifier "-" could not be bound

Tags: sql

I have this SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    dbo.ARTRNTBL.Item_code, dbo.ARTRNTBL.Item_name, dbo.FAFPHTBL.rate_value,
    dbo.FAFPHTBL.quantity, dbo.FAFPHTBL.total, dbo.FAFPHTBL.TIN, dbo.EGRDGTBL.return_type  
FROM
    dbo.FAFPHTBL 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ARTRNTBL     
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.EGRDGTBL ON dbo.FAFPHTBL.Item_code = dbo.ARTRNTBL.Item_code 
        ON dbo.ARTRNTBL.Item_code = dbo.EGRDGTBL.Item_code 
WHERE
    dbo.FAFPHTBL.invoice_no = '" & TextBox39.Text & "'"
```

I keep getting this error:

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.FAFPHTBL.Item_code" could not be bound.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way the join expressions are nested. At the time `dbo.FAFPHTBL.Item_code` is used, it's part of this expression:

```
dbo.ARTRNTBL INNER JOIN dbo.EGRDGTBL ON dbo.FAFPHTBL.Item_code = dbo.ARTRNTBL.Item_code
```

Notice the `dbo.FAFPHTBL` object is not included with this expression.

You probably want this instead:

```
SELECT dbo.ARTRNTBL.Item_code, dbo.ARTRNTBL.Item_name, dbo.FAFPHTBL.rate_value, 
    dbo.FAFPHTBL.quantity, dbo.FAFPHTBL.total, dbo.FAFPHTBL.TIN, dbo.EGRDGTBL.return_type  
FROM dbo.FAFPHTBL 
INNER JOIN dbo.ARTRNTBL ON dbo.FAFPHTBL.Item_code = dbo.ARTRNTBL.Item_code 
INNER JOIN dbo.EGRDGTBL ON dbo.ARTRNTBL.Item_code = dbo.EGRDGTBL.Item_code 
WHERE dbo.FAFPHTBL.invoice_no = @InvoiceNumber
```

While I'm here:

**DO NOT USE STRING CONCATENATION LIKE THAT TO INCLUDE A TEXTBOX IN THE QUERY!**

And yes, I know I'm shouting, because it's that important. If you're not using parameterized queries, you're practically *begging* for problems with your app, some of them pretty serious security issues. If you set me down in front of your app, I could easily delete all your data or elevate my permission to admin level.