# No default member found for type 'DBNull'. in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I've been struggling for the past few hours and still can't get my head round this one . The issue I am trying to update ARROMTBL table but it wont allow me.

```
 Dim rowCount As Integer = DataGridView7.Rows.Count
    For i = 0 To rowCount - 1

  If (DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value("RESALABLE") IsNot DBNull.Value) AndAlso DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value("RESALABLE") = "True" Then

            aditional = SARROMTBL + DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value

            cmd.CommandText = "update ARROMTBL SET Balance ='" & aditional & "'  WHERE Item_code = '" & DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "'"
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End If
Next
```

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues!

Comment: Also, I [already warned you about injection on your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64229178/3043) last week This is a **BIG DEAL**. It's too important to leave this stuff lying around your code. Now that I know should know better, you'll get no more help from me when posting questions with such glaring vulnerabilities. I can't be party to such obvious malpractice.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Do you have an error message or no update is taking place ? In that latter case it probably means there is a problem with your criteria. Print the resulting SQL command, verify this is what you want and test it. There are many other things to improve: the SQL injection vulnerability of course, but also other pitfalls. By default the user is allowed to **drag** columns in the DGV, so using column indexes is not safe at all. But you could use **named columns** instead.

Comment: And a better way of doing it would be to bind your DGV to a datatable/dataset and save the data back to the DB with SqlDataAdapter for example. You should find plenty of tutorials just by googling those keywords. There is no need to run that UPDATE, you could commit changes in bulk when you are done editing.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense:

```vb
DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value("RESALABLE")
```

What exactly do you think that is doing? This part gets the value from the cell:

```vb
DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
```

That value is presumably either going to be a `String` or `DBNull.Value`. I would assume that this:

```vb
If (DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value("RESALABLE") IsNot DBNull.Value) AndAlso DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value("RESALABLE") = "True" Then
```

really ought to be this:

```vb
Dim value = TryCast(DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value, String)

If value = "True" Then
```

The `TryCast` will take care of `DBNull.Value` or anything else that isn't a `String` by returning `Nothing`. Alternatively:

```vb
Dim value As Object = DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value

If value IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso CStr(value) = "True" Then
```

You could even take advantage of the fact that `DBNull.ToString` returns `String.Empty`:

```vb
If DataGridView7.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString() = "True" Then
```